# React - how to update state in parent component onclick in child - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent and child component and simply take the input and on click I want to sort of update the parent. My onChange function works, but onClick I get the error message: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined - meaning that I never actually updated the parent. I cant figure out what am I doing wrong because as I understand, Im am passing the function correctly. Anyone knows? Thanks!

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: 'Frarthur'};
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
 }

changeName(newName) {
    this.setState({
        name: newName
    });
}
handleInput() {
    console.log("helloooooo", this.state.name)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>               
            <Child name={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeName} onClick={this.handleInput}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
class Child extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInput2 = this.handleInput2.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(name);
}

handleInput2() {
    this.props.onClick()
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Hey my name is {this.props.name}!
            </h1>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleInput2}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: You need to bind `handleInput` in the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind them in your constructor, like you did w/ `changeName`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {name: 'Frarthur'};
  this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}
```

Alternatively, you could apply the proposed ES7 functionality (still considered "experimental" but extremely likely to be supported) p[roperty initializer](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/use-property-initializers-for-cleaner-react-components/) by using fat arrow function:

```
handleInput = () => {
    console.log("helloooooo", this.state.name)
};
```

Note, this may require you to update your project's configuration to support stage-0 preset for babel.

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) just one question for understanding. Since Im not updating my parents state insight my handleInput method, BUT inside my changeName method - why do I need to bind the handleInput method? My thinking (which is obviously wrong) is that, since the console.log inside handleInput fires without binding it to the parent scope and since my state is being updated by changeName, I thought binding handleInput isnt necessary?!

Comment: Good question - it's necessary because you're trying to access `this.state` but w/o binding it, the method has no reference to `this`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't bind the

```
handleInput()
```

method in the Parent component. Here is the corrected Parent component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {  
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { name: 'Frarthur' };
 this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
 this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
} 

changeName(newName) {
 this.setState({
  name: newName
 });
}
handleInput() {
 console.log("helloooooo", this.state.name)
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <Child name={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeName} onClick={this.handleInput} />
  </div>
)
}};
```